# How do we deal with Unix hair dryer questions when we encounter them?

Tags: discussion, fun

I should've posted this on the first day of April, but I forgot about it.

As we know, the trademark Unix isn't solely for the operating systems, other products are allowed to use that trademark if they're of different category and won't cause ambiguity.

UNIX Electronics (a Korean company manufacturing home appliances, such as hair dryers) is one such company, so what should we do when we encounter people asking Unix questions that isn't about the operating systems?

Comment: I guess it's the same as asking [blenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender) on [Blender.se] or [bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick) on [bricks.se]...

Comment: First you need to know, whether they use their hair dryer inside a container. In that case you should furthermore ask whether that container is located on a ship being half of steel and half of a smiling whale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close them as not about Unix & Linux within the scope defined in the [help centre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Unix and Linux Stack Exchange is for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.

and specifically questions about

> - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
> - The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
> - Shell scripting
> - Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)
> - UNIX C API and System Interfaces ( within reason )

Some questions about hair dryers running Unix-like systems may be included under the third bullet point, but otherwise are not within scope. There is little expertise here for expanding the site into other trademark domains, but the questions might fit on [one of the other network sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and could be migrated by a moderator after being flagged.